# munmap_chunk() error in when i free an allocated memory

Tags: c, linux, pointers, malloc

i have a `char* path` that is global, later i call a function that allocates memory and returns it, and path points to it, when i free it i get this error

the only way is to not free the pointer

```
void free_memory() {

    if(path!=NULL)
        free(path);//problem

}

char* ExtractPath(char*str)
{
    char*temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str))+1);
    bzero(temp,strlen(temp));
    char ch ='/';

    if( checkUrl(str)==1) {
        if(strncasecmp(str,"http://",7)==0)
            str+=7;

        if(strstr(str,"/")!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(temp,str);
            temp=strchr(temp,ch);
            strtok(temp,"\t");
        }
        else
            strcpy(temp,"/");
    }
    return temp;
}
path=ExtractPath(Users_input);//here the pointer points to the allocated memory that returned from the function the char*path is a global value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ExtractPath` does not return the value returned from `malloc`, there is no way to free the returned string. It is only legal to pass to `free` precisely the value you got back from `malloc`.

Once you do `temp=strchr(temp,ch);`, the original value returned from `malloc` is lost. Calling `free` on the value returned from `strchr` is not legal.

Here's one way to fix it:

```
char* ExtractPath(char*str)
{
    char* temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str))+1);
    char* orig = temp; /* save the value we got back from malloc */
    char* ret;
    char ch ='/';

    if( checkUrl(str)==1) {
        if(strncasecmp(str,"http://",7)==0)
            str+=7;

        if(strstr(str,"/")!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(temp,str);
            temp=strchr(temp,ch);
            strtok(temp,"\t");
        }
        else
            strcpy(temp,"/");
    }
    ret = malloc (strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(ret, temp); /* make a new copy to return */
    free(orig); /* pass what malloc returned to free */
    return ret; /* caller can free this since we got it back from malloc */
}
```

Comment: wow thanks it works

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the problem is with

```
 bzero(temp,strlen(temp));
```

The content of `temp` is indeterminate, passing that to `strlen()` would invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size **and
>   whose value is indeterminate.**

That said, regarding the error for `free()` part, you have to supply the **exact** pointer which was returned by `malloc()` or family.

Quoting chapter §7.22.3.3

> [...] Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.

In your code, you actually modify the original pointer stored in `temp` by saying

```
        temp=strchr(temp,ch);
        strtok(temp,"\t");
```

and return the "modified" `temp`.

Passing that `temp` to `free()` will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), once again.

Comment: i tried to remove it or just to change it to the size of str but i still get the same problem

Comment: @לואיגבר nope, `sizeof(str)` does not do what you think it does. Moreover, if you need 0-filled memory, why dont you use `calloc()` alraedy?

Comment: still dosn't work i tried callock and everything i dont know why this error is showen